# Randomly placing images within a <div> and ensuring uniform distribution

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

I have a rectangular html div with dimensions X by Y. Lets say the center of this div is at x(c) and y(c). I have N images of dimension x(i) and y(i). The images sizes are roughly around 1/8th of the containing div and each image size is different from the rest.

What could be a good way to place these images inside this div so that they are uniformly distributed (yet randomly placed) on each page load. Looking at a javascript implementation.

EDIT: After dascandys answer, I think I could have worded the question better. I meant a random sequence of image load on each page load yet keeping the look and feel balanced.

Comment: What do you mean by "uniformly distributed"?

Comment: Yeah given the sizes, they will surely overlap.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually looking for a random distribution. Truly random means that parts of it are empty and that in another corner two of them overlap.

If you want to go scientific, you can use a randomly generated Voronoi diagram with N points and Lloyd's algorithm to move those to a more uniform distribution.

If you prefer the practical approach, just put them in random spots and iteratively see if they're overlapping and if so, move them apart. For 8 images this'll be slower but still beyond human perception quick.

Comment: you are right, truly random spacing might not be uniform. I wanted to load this images up in a random sequence each time and keep the positions somewhat uniform to give the placement some balance. I will edit the question. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what [spatial Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process) was invented for. 
Try e.g. [this link](http://www-sop.inria.fr/ariana/DEMOS/building_extraction/proc_ponct.html) to see how to generate the points. I would go for some Monte Carlo method for generating random points in 2D (use google).

There is also one very simple method called **jittering**, but it is not so elaborated as Poisson and MC. You just define a rectangular maze of points and then just "jitter" the points randomly:

```
for i = 1 .. m
    for j = 1 .. n
        ouput point [i * maze_size + rand(maze_size/2), 
                     j * maze_size + rand(maze_size/2)]
```

Comment: Thanks, reading up Monte Carlo method. Can you also tell me what are m and n here?

Comment: @papdel: e.g. for 20 images you can make maze 5x4, so you put m = 5, n = 4. But as I said, this is a primitive method.